# What aspects of information theory are used in modern cryptography?

Tags: cryptanalysis, entropy, information-theory

In studying modern (and classical) cryptography, many notions from information theory crop up. Unicity distance, min-entropy, compression, encoding, etc. What parts of information theory should be part of the knowledge corpus of a working cryptographer?

Comment: To the mods: This question is within the scope of the site as I understand it. However I would not be offended if the community votes to close it; it is formatted more like a community wiki than a specific question.

Comment: I suspect this is too broad to be a good fit for this site: you could probably write a whole book about it.  (Also, the answer depends on what you mean by a "working cryptographer".)

Comment: I was afraid of that. I was hoping to get something resembling a table of contents for a book about the subject, but that might have been too ambitious.

Comment: By 'working cryptographer' I mean someone whose job it is to design, analyze and implement new cryptosystems; this covers industry cryptographers and academics alike.

Comment: It's hard to narrow something like that down into an answer that would fit SE. But you can get an initial idea by looking at the knowledge range of [people that have recently been recognized for their “Advances in Cryptography”](http://www.acm.org/press-room/news-releases/2013/goedel-prize-13/). Most start out with Computer Science and add Information Theory to it. Diving in deeper, you can check the education of [well known and/or successful cryptographers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cryptographers) to see if there are fields that best fit your (educational) interests and abilities.

Comment: Example: the parts of Information Theory that fit *my personal interests* best are Number Theory and Chaos Theory. Others might think different, have different interests, or different abilities — which might or might not fit cryptography better. *In the end, it depends on what exactly you want to end up doing as a “professional cryptographer” — do you want to invent, teach, analyze, …?* Every subfield of cryptography has it's own, individual requirements and expectations in education and knowledge range. (So *yes, your question is a bit too broad*. Even comments tend to grow beyond the usual.)

Comment: @e-sushi: This question seems rather narrower than your comments in my mind. I've never heard Number Theory referred to as part of information theory?